# Interaction with another java application which is an executable jar file

Tags: java, testing, jar, automated-tests, awtrobot

I'm writing a java application, but I need to launch another java application which is just a JAR file (**I do not have the source code**). This JAR file open a simple AWT app. In my code I need to click on a button, copy a value of a text field and use this String in my code.
But I have no idea of how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: If you can't find anything online, show us your [researches](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You add that JAR file into your project's classpath. Then you can use What ever the none restricted classes and others that is there in the JAR file. When you want to export this as another JAR file add that JAR file you used.